# Calculating the date, given amount of days after a custom Epoc

Tags: c++, datetime, c++-chrono

I have a custom Epoc date which is different from the hard coded Epoc in STL. I want to find out the new date which is after specific amounts of days.

```
std::string ReturnDateTimeAsString(long double NumberOfDaysSinceEpoc)
{
    std::istringstream iss("1200-01-01.00:00:00");  // My custom Epoc
    std::tm Time;
    iss >> std::get_time(&Time, "%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S");
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point MyEpoc = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&Time));
    std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<86400, 1>> Days(NumberOfDaysSinceEpoc);   // 86400: Seconds in a day
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point DateTime = MyEpoc + Days; // I get the error here!
    std::time_t TimeType = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(DateTime);
    return std::string(std::ctime(&TimeType));
}
```

The function argument can be decimal. For example, if I pass `4.25` to this function, I want to get the string `"1200-01-05.06:00:00"` from it (4 days and 6 hours after the Epoc).

I get the error message below in the line where I try to add the Epoc and `Days` variable.

```
Cannot convert from 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::duration<long double,std::ratio<0x01,0x0989680>>>'
to
'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::system_clock::duration>'

No suitable user-defined conversion from
"std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<1i64, 10000000i64>>>"
to
"std::chrono::system_clock::time_point"
```

How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring namespaces, `MyEpoc` has type `system_clock::time_point`, and `Days` has type `duration<long double, ratio<86400>>`.  The sum of these two types will have type:

```
time_point<system_clock, duration<long double, system_clock::period>>
```

You are trying to assign that type to:

```
system_clock::time_point
```

which is the same thing as:

```
time_point<system_clock, system_clock::duration>
```

`system_clock::duration` is specified to be some signed integral type (typically `long long`).  So the entire problem is in trying to convert a `long double`-based `time_point` into an integral-based `time_point`.  This can be done with `time_point_cast`:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point DateTime = 
  std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(MyEpoc + Days);
```

Whether that makes your function correct or not is another matter.  But this gets the type system working.

---

Using this [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), I can easily see that at least on my system, your epoch is not what you want it to be:

```
#include "date.h"

std::string
ReturnDateTimeAsString(long double NumberOfDaysSinceEpoc)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    istringstream iss("1200-01-01.00:00:00");  // My custom Epoc
    tm Time;
    iss >> get_time(&Time, "%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S");
    system_clock::time_point MyEpoc = system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(&Time));
    {
        using namespace date;
        std::cout << MyEpoc << '\n';
    }
    duration<long double, ratio<86400, 1>> Days(NumberOfDaysSinceEpoc);   // 86400: Seconds in a day
    system_clock::time_point DateTime = time_point_cast<system_clock::duration>(MyEpoc + Days); // I get the error here!
    time_t TimeType = system_clock::to_time_t(DateTime);
    return string(ctime(&TimeType));
}
```

This outputs for the epoch:

```
1969-12-31 23:59:59.000000
```

`mtkime`, at least on my system, is probably not valid back to 1200-01-01.

As it turns out, on my system this operation is limited by `numeric_limits<int32_t>::min()` seconds (`-2'147'483'648s`).  And `sys_days{1970_y/1/1} - 2'147'483'648s` is 1901-12-13 20:45:52.  Try to set the epoch any earlier than that and my system (OS X) craps out.

Using this [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), I've simplified your function, and it is testing correctly, assuming that you intended your epoch in the UTC timezone (if not, it is easy to change that):

```
#include "date.h"

using days_ld = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<86400>>;

std::string
ReturnDateTimeAsString(days_ld Days)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;

    constexpr auto MyEpoc = sys_days{1200_y/1/1};
    auto DateTime = round<seconds>(MyEpoc + Days);
    ostringstream out;
    out << DateTime;
    return out.str();
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << ReturnDateTimeAsString(days_ld{4.25}) << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
1200-01-05 06:00:00
```

I took the liberty of rounding your `long double` input to the nearest `seconds`.  If you would prefer something finer, say `milliseconds`, that is a simple change:

```
    auto DateTime = round<milliseconds>(MyEpoc + Days);
```

which changes the output to:

```
1200-01-05 06:00:00.000
```

Or:

```
auto DateTime = round<minutes>(MyEpoc + Days);
```

which changes the output to:

```
1200-01-05 06:00
```

By changing the argument of the function to the desired duration type (`days_ld`), your function is now both safer to use and more flexible.  For example your client can now also input `std::chrono::hours`:

```
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << ReturnDateTimeAsString(102h) << '\n';
```

and get the identical output.

If you would prefer some other format for the output string, that is also very easy.  More details are at these links:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki